# Use property using the value of multiple variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I know there's a possibility like this:

```js
let eventSelected = "333";

let bestResult = result.personal_records[eventSelected]?.single?.best 
                 //search like this: result.personal_records.333?.single?.best
```

but when I have more variables, I cannot to like this:

```js
let eventSelected = "333";
let type = "average"

let bestResult = result.personal_records[eventSelected]?[type]?.best //error syntax
```

Is there some solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For optional chaining with dynamic properties, use `?.[prop]`. In this case, it would be `?.[type]?.best`.